# Problem cancelling intent while filling intent parameter with word "disregard"

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-assistant

I have a google Action with intents that require slot/parameter filling. My Action was recently rejected by Google for leaving the mic open without prompting the user and I cannot resolve the issue.

As an example I have an intent named "trunk" which has a parameter "vehiclename".
I invoke the “trunk” intent without filling the vehiclename parameter. The assistant attempts to fill the first parameter by asking me “what is the vehicle name?” (verbiage I've defined to help with the slot filling). I respond with “disregard”. Then the assistant replies with “Sure, cancelling.” (or another similar phrase). I want to know where this response is coming from. The detailed response json is:

```
{
  "conversationToken": "[]",
  "expectUserResponse": true,
  "expectedInputs": [
    {
      "inputPrompt": {
        "richInitialPrompt": {
          "items": [
            {
              "simpleResponse": {
                "textToSpeech": "Sure, cancelling.",
                "displayText": "Sure, cancelling."
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "possibleIntents": [
        {
          "intent": "assistant.intent.action.TEXT"
        }
      ],
      "speechBiasingHints": [
        "$vehiclename"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "responseMetadata": {
    "status": {
      "message": "Success (200)"
    },
    "queryMatchInfo": {
      "queryMatched": true,
      "intent": "686ab942-5132-451b-9a16-16dbe8648ad0"
    }
  }
}
```

This response body has  `“expectUserResponse”: true` which explains why the mic is being left open. And since the phrase "sure, cancelling" doesn't prompt the user, it violates google's design guidelines.

What’s important about this is that I have not created this response! It is nowhere in our intents, and it is not being returned by our API webhook. Our webhook is not even being called in any of this example.

Syntactically it makes sense that google assistant would treat “disregard” as any of the other stop words (e.g. “stop”, “cancel”, “never mind”, etc.) but it doesn’t treat it the same. Any of those other words exits the app as one would expect.

Furthermore, none of these stop words are invoking a “quit” intent which has the `actions_intent_CANCEL` event attached to it. According to google’s documentation here: https://developers.google.com/assistant/df-asdk/conversation-exits when uttering any of these exit words, the conversation should be routed through to our “quit” intent, but it doesn’t.

I’ve also tried attaching the `actions_intent_NO_INPUT` action to our quit intent, but that also isn’t triggered in this situation. After the assistant has responded with “sure, cancelling”, the conversation is basically stuck there and I can’t invoke another intent or provide any more dialog to prompt the user.

Main takeaway:

1. Where is this “sure, cancelling” response coming from?
2. How do we route the conversation to another intent from that response so that we can prompt the user again OR
3. How do we route the word “disregard” in such a way to avoid this errant response? Can we disable it?
   reminder: this is only an issue when trying to fill an intent parameter, and it is only an issue with the word “disregard”

Comment: I found at the bottom of this page https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/intents-actions-parameters a comment on cancelling slot filling: "Cancel slot filling:
When the end-user says an exit phrase like "Cancel", "Stop it", "That's enough", etc., the agent replies with "Okay, canceled" and clears slot filling contexts." However, it doesn't offer any advice on what to do from there.

Comment: My only recourse was to migrate the action from dialogflow to the new action builder. This meant I needed to refactor my webhook, but at least there is better scene handling with action-builder. Now in this situation when I say "disregard" during slot filling, the action claims my webhook isn't responding (even though it doesn't even try to post to it). But at least now it closes the mic and exits 
